# In what program was this official Ubuntu ad made in

Tags: canonical

I have previously stumbled upon the official 10.10 UDS ad:

[image]

What program was this ad made in? Is the program on ubuntu? Is there a template?

Comment: I didn't know Sackboy used Ubnutu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely [Openshot video editor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openshot) [image: Install openshot].

> OpenShot Video Editor is a free, open-source, non-linear video editor. It can create and edit videos and movies using many popular video, audio, and image formats. Create videos for YouTube, Flickr, Vimeo, Metacafe, iPod, Xbox, and many more common formats!
>
> Features include:
>
> - Multiple tracks (layers),
> - Compositing, image overlays, and watermarks,
> - Support for image sequences (rotoscoping),
> - Key-frame animation,
> - Video and audio effects (chroma-key),
> - Transitions (lumas and masks),
> - 3D animation (titles and simulations) by using [Blender](http://packages.ubuntu.com/blender) [image: Install blender 2.58-svn37702-1ubuntu1],
> - Upload videos (YouTube and Vimeo supported).

[image]